# Repetition of classes in the list every 4 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I need to create a loop of classes every 4 items listed, something like this:

```
<ul class="list">
 <li class="1">Element 1</li>
 <li class="2">Element 2</li>
 <li class="3">Element 3</li>
 <li class="4">Element 4</li>
 <li class="1">Element 5</li>
 <li class="2">Element 6</li>
 <li class="3">Element 7</li>
 <li class="4">Element 8</li>
<ul>
```

I am using the following jquery code to add class:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("color-" + (i+1));
  });
});
```

Any idea what I can do? Thanks

Comment: So every 4th item should have a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list li").each(function(i) {
    var num = (i % 4) + 1;
    $(this).addClass("color-" + num);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`%` modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".list li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("color-" + ((i%4)+1));
  });
});
```

**jQuery demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ana3q/1

---

Or you could avoid javascript completely, and use the [`:nth-child()` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)

```
ul.list li:nth-child(4n+1){}
ul.list li:nth-child(4n+2){}
ul.list li:nth-child(4n+3){}
ul.list li:nth-child(4n+4){}
```

**CSS only demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Ana3q/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/sU39B/

```
$(function(){
  i=0;
  $('.list li').each(function(){
    if(i==4) i=0;
    i++;
    $(this).addClass('color-'+i);
  });
});
```

Comment: Other answers are way better. This one is just just simple to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use the selector `$(".list li:nth-child(4n)")`

Comment: the OP wants one class for each, not just the fourth

Comment: the 4n pick every 4th object. also, if you need it to start at the 4th element(4n+4)

Comment: i know,  But i believe that the asker wants to target each element in groups of 4. so first/second/third/fourth/first/second/third/...

Answer (score 0):

I think `:nth-child` will a good fit here

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('.list li:nth-child(4n + ' + i + ')').addClass(i + '')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X47aQ/)